# realloc struct of array inside function

Tags: c, dynamic, struct, malloc, realloc

I have made a library program to store movies in and using dynamic memory allocation for my struct array without success. Adding the first record (movie) works fine, but after the second the values are just messed up characters.

There is not really much more to say than showing my code.

The problem is that I can't `realloc` inside my function `addmovie();`

But if I put this line:

```
movie = (struct movies *) realloc(movie, (records+1) * sizeof(struct movies));
```

Right before calling `addmovie();` function it seems to work, why?

```
/* Global variables */
int records = 0; // Number of records

struct movies{
    char name[40];
    int id;
};

addmovie(struct movies **movie)
{
    int done = 1;
    char again;
    int index;

    while (done)
    {
        index = records;
        records++; // Increment total of records

        struct movies *tmp = (struct movies *) realloc(movie, (records+1) * sizeof(struct movies));

        if (tmp)
            *movie = tmp;

        system("cls");
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Enter name of the Movie: ");
        fgets(movie[index].name, 40, stdin);

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Enter itemnumber of the Movie: ");
        scanf("%d", &movie[index].id);

        printf("\nSuccessfully added Movie record!\n");

        printf("\nDo you want to add another Movie? (Y/N) ");
        do
        {
            again = getch();
        } while ( (again != 'y') && (again != 'n') );

        switch ( again )
        {
        case ('y'):
            break;

        case ('n'):
            done = 0;
            break;
        }
    } // While
}

int main()
{
    int choice;

    struct movies *movie;
    movie = (struct movies *) malloc(sizeof(struct movies)); // Dynamic memory, 68byte which is size of struct

    while (done)
    {
        system("cls");
        fflush(stdin);
        choice = menu(); //returns value from menu

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            addmovie(movie);
            break;
        }

    } // While

    free(movie); // Free allocated memory
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` or `realloc` in a C program.

Comment: you should increment the `records` in your code.

Comment: I am incrementing `records` after variable inputs have been done

Comment: I get error: request for member ' ' in something not a structure or union.
`fgets(*movie[index].name, 40, stdin);`
`*movie[index].id = input_number(&movie[index].id);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C is a pass-by-value language.  When you do:

```
movie = (struct movies *) realloc(movie, (records+1) * sizeof(struct movies));
```

In your function, `movie` from `main()` isn't affected at all.  You need to pass a pointer-to-a-pointer:

```
void addmovie(struct movies **movie)
```

and then modify the pointer's contents:

```
struct movies *tmp = realloc(...)
if (tmp)
   *movies = tmp;
```

Note that it's also important not to assign the return value of `realloc` back to the variable to passed to it - you might end up leaking.

Check the [comp.lang.c FAQ question 4.8](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html) for a complete explanation.

Comment: Might also be helpful to point out to OP that he is not checking the return value of `realloc` if it fails, the pointer to origanlly allocated memory is lost and he suffers a memory leak

Comment: I would have expected nothing less from you :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but could you explain a little more, first time working with dynamic arrays..
And what is this tmp thing?

Comment: are you making `tmp` a pointer to `*movie`?
and should i use tmp for my variables? let say `tmp[index].name` etc

Comment: @Pankrates still dont know how I should `realloc` my struct with the double pointer solution

Comment: @CarlNorum, Should I realloc using struct `movies *tmp = realloc(movie, (size))`
and use tmp for variables?
like so: `tmp[index].name`

Comment: @CarlNorum, I Think I got it to work now. I added the `&` in `addmovie(&movie);` and using tmp for my variables. Also is the if-statement some kind of error handling? Thanks a lot.